# System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda issue with Select() command

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use the `DynamicExpression` class to parse a string and get an expression tree.
This works fine for simple cases, but when the input string contains a `Select()` command, this gives me the error "No applicable aggregate method 'Select' exists".

For example, let's say I want to build the expression tree below:

```
x => x.MyCollection.Select(y => y.SomeInt)
```

If I pass the string `"x.MyCollection.Select(SomeInt)"` to the `ParseLambda` method, I get the error mentioned above.

Does anyone know to get around this or give me an alternative to transform a string to a lambda expression?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. It seems to me that Select and SelectMany methods are not defined in the System.Linq.Dynamic assembly version you are trying to use.

Edit: It seems a lot of the extension methods are missing - Take, Skip, SingleOrDefault, FirstOrDefault etc...